# Вопрос по woocommerce и advanced custom fields. На странице категории не отображается созданное произвольное поле

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Передо мной стоит задача: добавить произвольное поле в категорию woocommerce. Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Делаю следующим образом: Создаю группу полей, внутри создаю необходимое поле.  в условиях отображения ставлю «Таксономия записи» и выбираю необходимую категорию. Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В итоге, на выбранной странице данное поле не появляется. Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в следующем: я что-то не так делаю, или же делаю всё правильно и проблема в чем-то другом?

Comment: Скрины должны быть в вопросе. Исправь вопрос.

Comment: Таксономия товаров WooCommerce - это product.